# User assigned managed identity does not work with locally

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

User assigned managed identity doesn't work locally. Somehow it always uses my local account even I specified ManagedIdentityClientId.
What to specify in order to use user assigned managed identity ?
I've already assigned Azure Data Bus Owner role to User assigned identity

```
Console.WriteLine("Sending a message to the topic...");
    var clientId = "clientid";
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId, TenantId = "tenantId" });

    ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient("sbusname", credential);

    // Create a sender for the topic
    ServiceBusSender topicSender = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(TopicName);

    // Send a message to the topic
    string messageBody = "Hello, world!";
    var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
    await topicSender.SendMessageAsync(message);

    Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully!");

    // Close the Service Bus client
    await serviceBusClient.DisposeAsync();
```

I've also tried with ChainedTokenCredential and AzureCliCredential but no luck.

Comment: You would typically use your own user account when running locally. Managed Identities are used from within Azure.

Comment: Is there a way to test managed identities from local environment, just to confirm everything is working fine ?

Comment: What is the framework of your application?

Comment: I run this in .net core 6, not sure what framework has to do with it ?